# how to execute sls rule and take conditional action?

Tags: salt-stack

I want to have saltstack sls rule that periodically executes bash command. Depending on the command output, I want to send notification.

I already have the sls rule, and it executes periodically as expected. I have as well configuration to send out notifications and it works with salt-run:

```
 salt-run mattermost.post_message message='Test'
```

Question is - **how to make it work with .sls rule**? I would appreciate some example.

Otherwise I can write some python script for this. But maybe salt already support this?
Do I need reactor? https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a message if the state fails you can use the `onfail` requisite to send your mattermost message.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#onfail

```yaml
needs-restarting -r:
  cmd.run: []

notify failure:
  module.run:
    - mattermost.post_message:
      - message: Reboot is required
    - onfail:
      - cmd: needs-restarting -r
```

Comment: thanks for reply - I want to send message if ```needs-restarting -r``` return need of an reboot. Example output:
```Core libraries or services have been updated:
  linux-firmware -> 20191203-76.gite8a0f4c.el7

Reboot is required to ensure that your system benefits from these updates.```

Comment: I know I need use reactor.... struggling to make fire_event working with onfail

Comment: I have solution but its ugly - I call salt-run command from salt-state. I am quite dissappointed with SLS limited options.

Comment: @Wojtas.Zet you don't need a reactor if you're using `onfail`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to periodically do something, then use the [job scheduler](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/jobs/#scheduling-jobs).

If you want to do something in response to an asynchronous event, use the [reactor system](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/reactor/).

If you want to handle the result of a job in a particular way, use a different [returner](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/returners/).

The [state system](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/states/) is only for putting a system into a known state, not for running generic jobs. You can use a state to set up one of the above, however.

You can also write custom modules for all of the above, if the builtins are not sufficient.

It sounds like you want something like:

```yaml
my-daily-check:
  schedule.present:
    - function: cmd.run
    - job_args: 
      - /path/to/script.sh
    - returner: mattermost
    - when: 6pm
```